# Loading drivers after OS boot takes a long time

Tags: windows-7, drivers, wmi

My windows 7 x64 build boots fairly quickly (20s). It's a lab PC with very little installed.

After seeing the desktop, launching applications that load a custom driver (several different ones) take more than a minute to open. I searched for similar posts but none matched.

During the wait, windows task manager shows zero activity so it looks like a timeout issue.

After the first application is open, the rest will open instantly. All these apps also use WMI as far as I know.

The PC is disconnected from the network and I've tried disabling the network driver. No effect.

Has anyone managed to solve such an issue w/o a full reinstall of the OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer myself.
Setting the power plan to "High performance" did the trick, all the slow loading apps opened in a split second.

Why exactly did it change anything is another matter. From 1 minute to 1 second doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

Goto Start, then type "msconfig". This will bring up a system configuration window.

Goto the "Startup" tab. Here is a list of programs that will attempt to start running when windows runs.

These will run in a queue, so something there is slowing the others down. Try disabling a few and restarting the PC to find the issue.

Comment: nothing suspicious in there. this is a clean install